# Deciphering this regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
octet = /\d{,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/
ip_regex = /^#{octet}\.#{octet}\.#{octet}\.#{octet}/
```

The regex above is used to match an IP address. I understand that \d is used to match a digit, and I also understand the ip_regex part, but after looking at some tutorials I'm still not able to completely understand the octet part.
Could someone enlighten me? What does `{,2}|1` mean for example?

Comment: https://regex101.com

Comment: One could write `ip_regex = /^(?:#{octet}\.){3}#{octet}/`. Note `^` is the start-of-line anchor. If the start-of-string anchor is wanted use `\A` instead.

Comment: Easier would be `arr = str.split('.'); arr.size == 4 && arr.all? { |s| s =~ /\A\d+\z/ && s.to_i <= 255 }`. Better yet is `require 'ipaddr'; IPAddr.new(str).ipv4?`. If `str` is not a valid string representation of an IP address a syntax error is raised by `IPAddr.new(str)` (which have to be handled). See [IPAddr](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html).

Comment: The actual octet bit should be `octet = '(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])'` and ip regex `ip_regex = /\A#{octet}(?:\.#{octet}){3}\z/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does `{,2}|1` mean for example?

You should be looking at the parts separated by `|` – `\d{,2}` is a pattern, `1\d{2}` is a pattern, etc. Here’s what they mean:

- `\d{,2}` – up to 2 digit characters, i.e. numbers from 0 to 99
- `1\d{2}` – the digit 1 followed by 2 digits, i.e. numbers from 100 to 199
- `2[0-4]\d` – 2, then a digit from 0 to 4, then a digit, i.e. numbers from 200 to 249
- `25[0-5]` – 2, 5, and a digit from 0 to 5, i.e. numbers from 250 to 255

When you join them together with `|`, it’s the pattern matching any of those patterns, i.e. numbers from 0 to 255.

The `\d{,2}` pattern is a bit wrong because it also matches the empty string and allows a leading zero, which is inconsistent with the other patterns.

If you wanted to check whether an entire string matched the pattern, a correct version would probably be this:

```
octet = /\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/
ip_regex = /\A#{octet}\.#{octet}\.#{octet}\.#{octet}\z/
```

Comment: @Ry Your answer is better than mine, as it mentions empty strings and leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

One octet in an IP address (in dotted-octet notation) may not exceed 255.

So given `/\d{,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/`, break it apart like this: `/ \d{,2} | 1\d{2} | 2[0-4]\d | 25[0-5] /x`

The first snip, `\d{,2}`, matches a 1 or 2 digit number. The second snip, `1\d{2}`, matches any number between 100 and 199. The third snip, `2[0-4]\d`, matches any number between 200 and 249. The last snip, `25[0-5]`, matches any number between 250 and 255. Put them all together, and an octet may be any number between 1 and 255.

Comment: Last bit: 0 and 255

Comment: Yup. Now imagine how complex the regular expression would be if it followed the actual bitwise rules for valid IP address numbers...

Answer (score 0):

There is a really cool tool to help understanding regular expressions: https://regexper.com It gives you the finite-state automaton, which is more visual and easy to understand that the regular expression.

For example, for octet you [get](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cd%7B%2C2%7D%7C1%5Cd%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7C25%5B0-5%5D%2F):

[image: octet]

Although with the `{,2}` is still not very clear. `a{,2}` means maximum 2, so it is equivalent to `{0,2}` (between 0 and 2). Changing this in the regular expresion regexper makes it a bit better:

[image]

And now I think it is easy to read.

Another good tool to try your regular expression is [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/YKmpDDYHuV).